# How to fill a form field with no id or class using imacros?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am working on a website I need to submit a lot of data so I am using imacros to fill but one field remains blank. This is because it has no id or class and has a changeable "name". This value can change on every reload.

How do I fill this field with imacros.

```
<input value="" size="20" max-length="6" name="122637" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope using XPATH will solve you problem.. Find the Xpath of that field, and use it in the TAG, like below

```
TAG XPATH="//form[@id='demo']/fieldset[1]/ol/li[1]/input[1]" CONTENT="Gulam"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how imacros works, but try matching against all attributes

```
document.querySelector('input[value][size="20"][max-length="6"][type=text]')
```

Comment: how i will paste it on i macros?

Comment: document.querySelector is not matching other all is ok